# jstree get checked node without expanding

Tags: jstree

I am using jstree. I want to get all checked node lists without expanding jstree. Can I use the data parameter? But I am unable to use this parameter.

```
$("#jstree").jstree("get_selected")
```

is not working for me. what can i do?